# Entities of immutable classes

Tags: java, hibernate

As per [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch12.html#readonly-api-immutable), it says:

### 12.1.1. Entities of immutable classes

> Hibernate treats a persistent entity of an immutable class the same
>   way as a read-only persistent entity of a mutable class. **The only
>   exception is that Hibernate will not allow an entity of an immutable
>   class to be changed so it is not read-only.**

It is not clear on what the statement in bold text indicates. Can someone please help me in understanding this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate lets you change a read-only entity or proxy of a mutable class so it is no longer read-only:

```
Session.setReadOnly(entityOrProxy, false);
```

After that, a mutable `entityOrProxy` that has been previously set to read-only, is no longer read-only. The documentation simply says that Hibernate does not let you make the same call for an immutable class.

Comment: Such as String, Long, Integer